# How to divide UnitMass in Swift?

Tags: swift, user-input, units-of-measurement

I am trying to build a simple app that allows the user to input their weight, input their goal weight, and input how much they plan to lose each week.

I want it to return saying, for example (You weigh 12 stone and 2 lbs, you want to weigh 10 stone and 0 lbs, if you lose 2 lbs a week, you will reach your goal in 15 weeks).

(Please note I am very new to Swift, I am more used to Python. I am hoping to create a calculator based on preset equations).

I have tried starting with the values as Integers and Doubles and then converting to UnitMass at the end with no luck

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

// enter your current weight
var myCurrentWeight = Measurement(value:12, unit: UnitMass.stones)

//enter your goal weight
var myGoalWeight = Measurement(value:10, unit: UnitMass.stones)

//enter how much you plan to lose a week
var weightLoss = Measurement(value:2, unit: UnitMass.pounds)

// find the difference inbetween the weights (Example: 12st - 10st = 2st)
let weightDifference = myCurrentWeight - myGoalWeight

//find out how many weightLoss's fit into the difference, this
let numOfWeeks = weightDifference / weightLoss

// print the number of weeks it takes to reach your goal
print(numOfWeeks)
```

Expected it to print: 28
The error I get is: "Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'Measurement' operands"

Comment: Your edit just undid the fixes to your formatting. Please fix your formatting before posting. Put some effort into making it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Removed edit. Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: You wish to divide a value in stones by a value in pounds and somehow get a number of weeks. `weightLoss` would need to be in a unit of "pounds per week" for the math and units to work out. But the `Measurement` API doesn't directly support multiplication or division with two `Measurement` instances.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Measurement type to convert between values, like so:

```
import Foundation

// this is a Double
var myCurrentWeight = 12.0

// this is a Double
var myGoalWeight = 10.0

// Convert Double value `2` as pounds to Double value as stones
var weightLoss = Measurement(value:2, unit: UnitMass.pounds).converted(to: UnitMass.stones).value

// find the difference inbetween the weights (Example: 12st - 10st = 2st)
let weightDifference = myCurrentWeight - myGoalWeight

//find out how many weightLoss's fit into the difference, this
let numOfWeeks = weightDifference / weightLoss

// print the number of weeks it takes to reach your goal
print(numOfWeeks)
```

This defines a value and it's unit: `Measurement(value:2, unit: UnitMass.pounds)`. Which you can then convert to another unit `.converted(to: UnitMass.stones)`

Use `Measurement` to convert values of different units and to be able to calculate with them.

Use `.value` on your `Measurement` instance to get it's `Double` representation, use that for calculating.